# How can i insert google adsense code in the different section(e.g h2, <p>) of content section?

Tags: javascript, php, content-management-system, adsense

I have simple CMS in PHP. I have page article.php where I display each posts of my website. I recently got google adsense approved and begin to insert its code inside home page and article.php page. It was easy to insert in other sections like above the content, below it and other visible html tags.
But I found hard to insert inside content[body] of the post like below or after h2 tags or after certain paragraph.
My article.php is displaying content written with CKEditor like this:

```html
<!-- Content -->
    <div class="content clearfix">

        <!-- Main Content -->
        <div class="main-content single">
            <h1 class="post-title"><?php echo $post['title']; ?></h1>
            <div class="post-content">
                <?php echo html_entity_decode($post['body']); ?>
            </div>           
        </div>
        <!--// Main Content -->
```

Can anyone help me to do this with certain controls based on length of each post. (I have made this CMS by learning online resources). Thanks in advance.

Comment: You said it was easy to insert ads in some sections. How do you insert it? It's not clear what do you mean by "hard to insert" - did you add an `<ins>` tag for ad but it wasn't filled with an ad?

Comment: @MikitaBelahlazau I simply want to insert adsense code in the 'body' section of the post. So, i can display 2-3 ads depending on the length of my content. Hope it's clear now.